# How to jenerate JSON format using wrapper class?

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, wrapper-class, jsongenerator

Please see the below code I have done some modification,

@RestResource(urlMapping='/instructionsRestCall/*')
global with sharing class InstructionsRestService {
    @HttpGet
    global static List getInstructions(){

```
    RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse response = RestContext.response;

    String instId = request.requestURI.subString(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/'));
    //Send list of Instruction details as per the provided JSON format for Instruction records where Category Type Code (catTypeCd__c) is not null
    List<Instructions__c> instList = [select Country__c,Category__c,SubCategory__c,Requirements__c,catTypeCd__c from Instructions__c];
    system.debug('Instructions List->>>>'+instList);      

    List<requestTypes> catWrapList = new List<requestTypes>();

    List<countryWrapper> counWrapList = new List<countryWrapper>();
    for(Instructions__c ins : instList){
        if(ins.catTypeCd__c != null){

            countryWrapper countWrap = new countryWrapper();
            requestTypes catWrap = new requestTypes();
            caseTypes innWrap = new caseTypes();

            countWrap.corpCode = ins.Country__c;
            catWrap.name = ins.Category__c;
            innWrap.name = ins.SubCategory__c;
            innWrap.value = ins.Requirements__c;
            innWrap.categoryTypeCode = ins.catTypeCd__c;
            countWrap.requestTypes = catWrap;
           // countWrap.innerWrapper = innWrap;
            countWrap.requestTypes.caseTypes = innWrap;
            counWrapList.add(countWrap);
        }    
    }
    system.debug('Result from WrapperList->>>>'+counWrapList);
    return counWrapList;
    //return JSON.serialize(counWrapList);
}        

global class countryWrapper{
    public String corpCode{get;set;}
    public requestTypes requestTypes{get;set;}
    //public innerWrapper innerWrapper{get;set;}
}
global class requestTypes{
    public String name{get;set;}
    public caseTypes caseTypes{get;set;}
}
global class caseTypes{
    public String name{get;set;}
    public String value{get;set;}
    public Double categoryTypeCode{get;set;}
}
```

}

I want this this corpCode will be in first position and after that requestType. What is wrong with my wrapper. Thanks in advance,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate the format specified because it is not valid JSON.

A map always requires a key for each element, and you are missing that structure here:

```
        {
            "something",
             [
                {
                    Subcategory__c: "something",
                    Requirements__c: "something",
                    catTypeCd__c: "1234",
                }
            ]
        }
```

More generally, if you want to generate a JSON map, you need to be serializing an Apex object (where each field becomes a key, and its value the corresponding value), or an actual Apex `Map` instance. As you can see in your generated JSON, this structure:

```
global class categoryWrapper{
    public String category{get;set;}
    public innerWrapper innerWrapper{get;set;}
}
```

does not produce a JSON map where the key `category` maps to the value of `innerWrapper`. To get a result like that, you'd need something along the lines of

```
global class categoryWrapper{
    public innerWrapper category {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I have now getting the following response- [ {
  "requestTypes" : {
    "name" : "On Road Programs - Taxable Benefit-FA",
    "caseTypes" : {
      "value" : null,
      "name" : "Question",
      "categoryTypeCode" : 401.0
    }
  },
  "corpCode" : "USA"
} ]                                      All I need to serialize the json structure like first "corpCode":"USA" after that rest of things.

Comment: Okay, did you see the details in my answer above about how JSON serialization works?

Comment: so my final json structure -   [ { 
  "corpCode" : "USA",
  "requestTypes" : {
    "name" : "On Road Programs - Taxable Benefit-FA",
    "caseTypes" : {
      "value" : null,
      "name" : "Question",
      "categoryTypeCode" : 401.0
    }
  }
} ]

Comment: Here is my wrapper-  global class countryWrapper{
        public String corpCode{get;set;}
        public requestTypes requestTypes{get;set;}
        //public innerWrapper innerWrapper{get;set;}
    }
    global class requestTypes{
        public String name{get;set;}
        public caseTypes caseTypes{get;set;}
    }
    global class caseTypes{
        public String name{get;set;}
        public String value{get;set;}
        public Double categoryTypeCode{get;set;}
    }

Comment: Rahul, stop please. This is not what comment threads are for. You are welcome to edit your original question post if you need to add more detail and information. If you need clarification on some specific point in the answer, use a comment to ask for that clarification.

Comment: Sorry David I have modified my question